# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application error after this command ON WINDOWS

Tags: rest, curl

im trying to issue this following command using cURL on a windows 7 box but i get a `"could not resolve host: application" error`

any ideas?

```
curl -c cookies.txt -H “Content-Type: application/json” -X POST -d \
‘{“username”:”alejandro”,”password”:”123ABC”}’ \
http://192.168.1.25/cv_api/sessions
```

thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have fancy quotes around the Content-Type and JSON string.  Change them to regular quotes and it should work.

Comment: thx, i changed it to regular quotes and im still having the problem :/

Comment: it'd be suitable if you update the question with exactly the string you're using...

Comment: im using this string:

curl -c cookies.txt -H “Content-Type: application/json” -X POST -d \ ‘{“username”:”alejandro”,”password”:”123ABC”}’ \
http://192.168.1.25/cv_api/sessions